# I cant reach the url desired with curl

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I try curl a website for show it in mine but always I stuck in a white page. I think because it have a redirection to a login form but I dont sure if is the reason because I failed. You can access the url that I use without login.

Here the code

```
$url = "http://www.faf.es/pnfg/NPcd/NFG_CmpJornada?cod_primaria=1000120&CodCompeticion=16867461&CodGrupo=17910021&CodTemporada=15&CodJornada=26&Sch_Codigo_Delegacion=1&Sch_Tipo_Juego=2";


$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 99999);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

htmlentities($output);
```

The html result:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!--
<h1>No se ha aceptado el cookie</h1>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

Comment: @ForgeWebDesign still nothing.

Comment: what is the output of `$output` variable? Can you `var_dump`? Did you have html result? If `$output` is empty. I think you must set `CURLOPT_HEADER`, `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` and `CURLOPT_REFERER` options.

Comment: @Enver, Yes I have the result. I will the question for add it. The results is a empty page with a comment in spanish say "
Cookie has not been accepted"

Comment: Yes, response is empty from web server, it understood the request did not come from browser or respectful client. You must try my first comment.

Comment: I tried but nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

Your request url only validate requests which have `JSESSIONID` cookie. So before you must grab valid cookie:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.faf.es/pnfg/NPcd/NFG_CmpJornada?cod_primaria=1000120&CodCompeticion=16867461&CodGrupo=17910021&CodTemporada=15&CodJornada=26&Sch_Codigo_Delegacion=1&Sch_Tipo_Juego=2";

$ch = curl_init();
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 99999);


$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

This gives you three headers for requests:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Movido temporalmente
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=648967C5FC907B1225EC61E9A65443E5; Path=/pnfg
Location: http://www.faf.es/pnfg/NLogin
Content-Length: 0 Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 19:33:30 GMT
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 302 Movido temporalmente 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9973308FA3AF81BE66C2F8C124671870; Path=/pnfg
Location: http://www.faf.es/pnfg/NLogin?NSess=1
Content-Length: 0 Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 19:33:30 GMT
Connection: close 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-15
Content-Length: 117
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 19:33:30 GMT
Connection: close
```

We have three header result because we said, request has `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option. So, we made three request in curl.

I identified, second `JSESSIONID` cookie value is valid. So, for getting web site information we must use cookie as below:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.faf.es/pnfg/NPcd/NFG_CmpJornada?cod_primaria=1000120&CodCompeticion=16867461&CodGrupo=17910021&CodTemporada=15&CodJornada=26&Sch_Codigo_Delegacion=1&Sch_Tipo_Juego=2";


$ch = curl_init();
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Secondary request cookie.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "JSESSIONID=9973308FA3AF81BE66C2F8C124671870");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 99999);


$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

When web site content comes, do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should revisit the [`htmlentities()` documentation](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) again; it doesn't do what it appears you believe it does.

In short, `htmlentities()` returns a `string`. You aren't capturing or otherwise outputting this `string` result anywhere. Use [`echo`](https://www.php.net/echo) (or similar) to make sure the result of `htmlentities($output)` is output to where you expect it.

```
$url = "http://www.faf.es/pnfg/NPcd/NFG_CmpJornada?cod_primaria=1000120&CodCompeticion=16867461&CodGrupo=17910021&CodTemporada=15&CodJornada=26&Sch_Codigo_Delegacion=1&Sch_Tipo_Juego=2";


$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 99999);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo htmlentities($output);
```

Comment: On a slightly tangential note, your script may not quite function exactly the way you intend it to, anyway. If there are scripts, relative references, etc. on the target page, `echo`ing them in the context of your domain will likely break **a lot** of the retrieved page's functionality. You might be interested in running a pre-fab proxying solution instead, as these solutions will generally account for these (and other more edge-) cases.

Comment: I know htmlentities does. I check values from Inspect > elements from the browser. And no, it isnt the result that I expect. I dont need any page's functionality, only show data from that web